# Term for derogatory suffix used with city names?

Tags: idioms, slang, geography, portmanteau-words

When speaking of a city in negative terms one might attach a prefix/suffix to the city name. This nickname is a portmanteau that implies a derogatory tone. Most often this will be a negative term but can also be another geographic name. Is there a specialized term for this use? I'm particularly interested in a term for the geographic modifier case.

Examples:

- I live in Spokcompton. (Spokane + Compton)
- He lives in Fayettnam. (Fayetteville + Vietnam)
- Hollyweird
- Fithadelphia

Comment: 'Bathrobe' would obviously be a port-manteau.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Seems to me that *bathrobe* is the manteau itself.

Comment: Seems to me that _Bath_ (Maine) is the port and _robe_ will do for the manteau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no extant word in English to use for this concept.

A possible neologism is

> demodysphemism

a portmanteau of 'demonym', the name of a place, and 'dysphemism',  derogatory term used for a neutral one.

Comment: Nothing wrong with creating a new term. I like it.